# Moment.js does not accepts variable as parameters

Tags: javascript, timestamp, momentjs

I am using moment.js to find the time difference between two intervals .

Here is my JS code :

```
console.log("from_url "+from_url); //prints: 2016-05-03T10:00:00
var a = moment(from_url);
console.log("a "+a); //prints : 1462294800000 isntead of 2016-05-03T10:00:00
```

Hence, I am not able to get the exact difference. 
Can anyone suggest where am I going wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you convert a moment object to a primitive using +, `Object.prototype.valueOf()` has been overridden to produce the unix timestamp in milliseconds - or what the ES2015 standard refers to as a 'time value'. As such, you are seeing is THAT value being printed out.

If you want the date, just use `.format()`:

```
var a = moment("2016-05-03T10:00:00"); "a " + a.format()
"a 2016-05-03T10:00:00-05:00"
```

Note that format takes numerous parameters: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

As far as finding the difference between two dates and times goes - you should be constructing two moments and using moment's `.diff()` function to compare: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/

For example, to get the difference in hours between your date and now:

```
moment("2016-05-03T10:00:00").diff(moment(), 'hours')
-155
```